# Having a Navigation Controller & Tab Bar Controller in the same App

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Good day everyone,

I'm sure there is someone out there that is able to help me with the following:

I would like to structure my app with a set of log-in/sign-up screens using a navigation controller but then once the user has signed in I want to structure the app in a tab bar controller format.

I have no clue how to implement the "handing over" of the two controllers?

Any suggestions on material out there explaining this?

Comment: One possibility: start with a tab bar controller, but only give it a single tab for navigating through login.  When login is complete, call `setViewControllers` to give the tab bar controller the array of controllers that you want for the rest of the app.

Comment: @PhillipMills is there any possibility that I could make it work by starting with the navigation controller? I have a complicated sign-up procedure because I have two different types of users so I am kind of forced to start with the navigation controller.

Comment: It doesn't seem quite as simple, but there's this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621581-rootviewcontroller

Comment: @PhillipMills Thank you, I will have a look. Also, just to mention - once sign up is done I use a button to transition to the home screen (where I'd like the tab bar to root start) so I am in effect leaving the navigation controller and not returning to it again. Is there no way in the App Delegate to state that the tab bar should take over after the home screen is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Present Navigation controller on TabBar with modalPresentationStyle = fullScreen.
(presentationStyle is required for iOS 13+ so user can't swipe down and close login)

Since login is required, don't add cancel button. Once user is logged-in, dismiss navigation controller.

Things to keep in mind.

- TabBar needs to be loaded before presenting LoginFlow. So users will see initial tab bar content for quick second. Create not logged-in state for initial view.
- Once Login view is closed viewWillAppear will get called. So you can reload tab bar view with logged-in state.